# Add Key, Value pair to existing array with a condition to format the Key

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an below array:

```
  var array = [
    [
      '20160221',
      '10'
    ],
    [
      '20160307',
      '20'
    ]
  ];
```

Would like to convert to the below format (also changing the date from 20160221 to 2016-02-21)

```
var new = [ {date: '2016-02-21', value: '10'}, {date: '2016-03-07', value: '20'} ];
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you're tried to solve the problem, add the code in question. if not, you can try `map()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a example code:

```
var array = [
    [
      "20160221",
      "10"
    ],
    [
      "20160307",
      "20"
    ]
  ];

var newArr =  array.map(function(item){
  return {date:item[0].replace(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/,'$1-$2-$3'),value:item[1]};
});

console.log(newArr);
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/pejocilado/edit?html,js,output)